# マルチテナントサービス内でデータソースをユーザーごとに分けたい

Tags: java, mysql, aws, spring-boot

マルチテナントのサービスを開発する予定があります。
各ユーザー（サービス利用者）が所持する外部システムから、本サービスのデータベースを直接参照することを想定しています。
その際に他のユーザーのデータを参照できてしまわないよう、ユーザーごとにデータソースを分けたいと考えています。
何か有用な手段はありますでしょうか。

環境はAWS
アプリケーションはJava SpringBoot（5.0.6）
RDSはAmazon RDS for MySQL(5.7.33)

Comment: システムの構成もわかりませんし、「有用な手段」として求められているのが実現方式なのか実装方法なのかもわかりません。具体的な要件や設計情報を開示してもらわないと答えようがないですが、それは無理だと思いますので、お金払って人に頼むことをお勧めします。

Answer (score -1):

一つ案を言います：

テーブルをユーザごとに分けて作成する、ユーザ名の前にプレフィックスをつけてください、プレフィックスを付けることで他のテーブルとの名前をかぶらないようにすることができます。